# how can I get stronger staining for my lymph node sections

Tags: human-biology, molecular-biology, cell-biology, immunology, molecular-genetics

[image][image]I am using the same protocol and same antibodies that the literature says but still I cannot get good staining for my lymph node sections, I tried to change the fixation method and I am using now acetone instead of PFA, I also tried with acetone plus ethanol, the antibody concentration used worked in previous sections. 
How could I increase the signal and/or remove the noise?

It also happened to work in some sections before but not in others even I did exactly the same, why could that be if I am using the same tissue?

Thanks

Comment: could you upload example of microscopic image

Comment: Is the tissue you are staining now the same age (i.e., time from initial fixation to staining) as the tissue you used before?

Comment: yes I do the fixation just before the staining so I treat them in the same way

Comment: I attached the picture, thats the pic of the channel for Madcam which is my interest

Comment: Did you try a different fluorophore or fresh antibody? What're you using now? And are you getting signal with other markers like DAPI? What does your staining efficiency look like by FACS? Strong separation from negative or weak? Maybe try digesting some lymph node and see if you get good staining.

Comment: the antibodies are not fresh but some times work better than other using the same kind of tissue, so I guess is depending of the tissue and age of animal or sections? the stainning efficiency looks okay. I used Dapi, Cy3, FITC 647 and alexa488.

Comment: @bio Okay, and your laser/filter setup are appropriate for your fluorophores? If we rule out hardware and reagents, all that's left the the protocol and the slides.

Comment: @bio what's your red laser filter setup?

Comment: I can double check on Monday because I do not remember now, but I checked that time ago with my supervisor and it was fine. I upload now another image (first one) so as you can see, doing the same fixation protocol and staining steps I get very big variations within the same tissue. I also tried different ab incubations, different concentration of the primary and secondary ab and all of them look with a lot of noise so Im not sure now what is real signal and how to avoid this big variation between same kind of tissue.